# Error when using the polymerize API for HMS location

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-location-kit

When I use the polymerize API of Huawei and if I included com.huawei.instantaneous.location.sample, the polymerize API does not work --

if I do not include it, it does "work".

```
{"dataTypeName":"com.huawei.instantaneous.location.sample"},

{"dataTypeName":"com.huawei.instantaneous.heart_rate"},

{"dataTypeName":"com.huawei.continuous.calories.burnt"},

{"dataTypeName":"com.huawei.instantaneous.speed"}],

"startTime":1448940711000,"endTime":1448943334000}
```

Any idea or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.huawei.instantaneous.location.sample is public atomic data types but not public statistical data types. so when you included com.huawei.instantaneous.location.sample, the polymerize API does not work.

Pls refer to [this website](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/public-dt-0000001050069714-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001051066438__section12310165610234) for more info.